# Fetch data from sqlite in parts

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview

I have 10000+ of data in SQLite database. I am trying to fetch data in parts like I am trying to fetch first 100 records of data and store in an array and than try to fetch next 100 records of data but I am not able to make the query like that which can fetch first 100 records than fetch next 100 records and so on..
Here is my code of fetchAllData

```
- (void)getAllData {
    NSString * convertInttoStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rowNumber];
    // Getting the database path.
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"iandroidquran_database 3.sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [database open];
    NSString *sqlSelectQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                @"SELECT * FROM qSurahContent WHERE surahID=%@ LIMIT 100 " ,
                                convertInttoStr];


    // Query result
    FMResultSet *resultsWithNameLocation = [database executeQuery:sqlSelectQuery];
    while([resultsWithNameLocation next]) {
        NSString *strID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[resultsWithNameLocation intForColumn:@"surahID"]]
```

[surahContentArabic addObject:strName];

```
    }
    if (rowNumber == 1) {
        [surahContentArabic removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [self.tblView reloadData];

    [database close];
}
```

and Here is the method on which populate it in a tableview.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString * cellIdentifierImage = @"ImageCell";
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        CustomTableViewCell * cell = [self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifierImage];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
    CustomTableViewCell * cell = [self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
       cell.surahContenArab.text = [surahContentArabic objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)];
        cell.ayahLbl.text = [ayahId objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1)];

        return cell;
    }


}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row + 100 > [self.surahContentArabic count])
    {
        [self getAllData];
    }
}
```

Please tell me the solution how I can fetch data in parts . Thanks

Comment: Please See This Link :- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_limit_clause.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select records `100-200` (inclusive) you have to use the `LIMIT OFFSET` clause.

> SELECT * FROM qSurahContent WHERE surahID=%@ LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100

The above query returns `100` records, start from `record 101` (OFFSET 100).

You can change `OFFSET value 200` for 3rd set of records.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I am trying that but it if I fetched all the records than the empty cell appears at the end because I am trying to fetch the record in  this method
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

Comment: Refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528800/ios-how-to-make-the-tableview-use-paginated-api-output